# Are full nodes/archivals execute the whole blockchain when a block received?

Tags: blockchain, nodes

Are full archive nodes and full nodes the same? I know that when the full nodes get a transaction, it verfies it by executing it. Does it execute the transactions in previous blocks too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are full archive nodes and full nodes the same?

Yes. A full node contains all the data pertaining to all previous transactions.

> I know that when the full nodes get a transaction, it verifies it by executing it.

Yep, correct.

> Does it execute the transactions in previous blocks too?

When a user first creates a full node, the first thing the node must do is to download all the blockchain data from another full node, up until the latest block.

Part of the process of downloading this data is also to replay, and therefore verify, the state transitions associated with all the transactions contained in all of the downloaded blocks.

Only by doing this can the new full node know that its most up-to-date state is valid, and hasn't been corrupted either by accident, or maliciously by a peer node.

Comment: I see, and how about nodes which are not new, do they execute the whole blockchain when they receive a block?

Comment: They execute (verify) all the transactions in the new block, yes.

Comment: only the transactions in the new block, not in previous blocks... I see. thank you